# Cast template (matrix) class

Tags: c++

I have a template matrix class from which I want to cast an instance of one type into one of another type (e.g. `Matrix<int>` to `Matrix<double>`) in an intuitive way.

The header file containing the class looks as follows:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

template <class T> class Matrix
{

  private:

    std::vector<T>      _data;
    std::vector<size_t> _shape;
    std::vector<size_t> _strides;

  public:

    Matrix               (const Matrix<T> &) = default;
    Matrix<T>& operator= (const Matrix<T> &) = default;

    Matrix<T>(){};

    // explicit constructor
    Matrix<T>( size_t nrow , size_t ncol )
    {
      _shape.push_back(nrow);
      _shape.push_back(ncol);

      while ( _data.size()<_shape[0]*_shape[1] )
        _data.push_back((T)0);
    };

    T& operator[] ( size_t i )
    { return _data[i]; };

    T& operator() ( size_t i, size_t j )
    { return _data[i*_shape[1]+j]; };

    size_t size ( void ) const
    { return _data.size(); };

    std::vector<size_t> shape ( void ) const
    {
      std::vector<size_t> ret(2);
      for ( size_t i=0 ; i<2 ; i++ )
        ret[i] = _shape[i];
      return ret;
    };

};

#endif
```

To me, the most intuitive way is one of the following two options (N.B. lines below *Option X* don't compile):

```
#include "matrix.h"

int main ( void )
{
  Matrix<int> matInt({5,5});

  for ( size_t i=0 ; i<matInt.size() ; i++ )
    matInt[i] = static_cast<int>(i);

  // Option 1
  Matrix<double> matDouble = matInt;

  // Option 2
  Matrix<double> matDouble = static_cast<Matrix<double>>(matInt);

  return 0;
}
```

---

At the moment I use the following solution (which I'm not super fond about since it is too custom for something trivial):

```
Matrix<double> as_double ( void ) {
  Matrix<double> out(this->shape());

  for ( size_t i=0 ; i<this->size() ; i++ )
    out[i] = static_cast<double>(_data[i]);

  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<T>`is not assignable to `std::vector<U>` so you can’t just assign your members, but have to do the conversion explicitly.

You can write a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

```
template<typename U,
typename V = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, U>::value>::type>
operator Matrix<U> () {
    Matrix<U> mat(shape()[0], shape()[1]);
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size() ; ++i) {
        mat[i] = static_cast<T>(_data[i]);
    }
    return mat;
}
```

The `enable_if` (`#include <type_traits>`) can be removed, but I advice to keep it, because it disallows silent passage of i.e. `Matrix<std::string> mat = Matrix<int>();`

Also it’s probably a good idea to use `_data.resize(_shape[0] * _shape[1]);` in your ctor, because you currently have unnecessary algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a "templated copy constructor" (sort of). Let's start by cleaning up your existing constructor:

```
Matrix<T>( size_t nrow , size_t ncol )
```

That's not necessary. You can simply declare the inlined constructor as:

```
Matrix( size_t nrow , size_t ncol )
```

Then, define a templated pseudo-copy constructor:

```
template<typename From>
Matrix(const Matrix<From> &s)
```

Now, write this constructor as if you were writing a copy-constructor.

Afterwards, you should also write a templated assignment operator

```
template<typename From>
Matrix &operator=(const Matrix<From> &f)
```

Again, pretend that this is an ordinary assignment operator, and go through the motions of implementing one.